# Python INI to Dictionary - Loop through all items in section

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a newbie to Python and just got started with reading Windows INI file into Python Dictionary object. This is the method that I follow

```
import ConfigParser

class MyParser(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):
    def as_dict(self):
        d = dict(self._sections)
        for k in d:
            d[k] = dict(self._defaults, **d[k])
            d[k].pop('__name__', None)
        return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = MyParser()
    f.read("/DIRECTORY_TO/setup.ini")
    d = f.as_dict()
```

My INI file like any other Standard INI file looks like this

```
[A]
Name = XYZ
Age = 23
[B]
Name = DEF
Age = 19
```

The file gets loaded and based on the len(d) I can see that items are getting loaded into the Dictionary object. Now how do I loop / iterate through all the items (key, value) in each section? This is only my 2nd day with Python so I am unable to figure this out.

Thanks a ton,
MM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate through a dictionary `d`, use something like this:

```
for k in d:
    print('The key is {} and the value is {}'.format(k, d[k]))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a ton. But when I read from the file the 'order' of keys goes haywire. For example when I read from the above mentioned example ini file, the output that I get is The key is A and the value is {'Age': '23', 'Name': 'XYZ'} The key is B and the value is {'Age': '19', 'Name': 'DEF'}. I want to retain the same order as it is in the INI file from where it was read. Perhaps OrderedDict is the way but not too sure how to use that.

Comment: In a Python dictionary, the keys are not ordered—no matter what order you use when putting the keys in the dictionary, Python is allowed to rearrange them as it sees fit. If you need to preserve a certain order then try an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: great thanks...btw one small clarification...Sections have "key=value". So how do I loop through the key=value pairs inside a section. When I do this for k in d:
    print('The key is {} and the value is {}'.format(k, d[k])) what I get is Section Name and then entire list of keys + value as a string

Comment: You’ll need to adapt the parser to parse the data within sections too.

Comment: Okie... thanks a ton...I guess I will assign the value part to another Dictionary object to tackle that. Thanks once again. It was quick and helpful.